# DOM PDF Page break, if height is larger in <tr> tag

Tags: html, css, dompdf

I know we can use page break if we want to break the page but I want it dynamically for , I have tr which is having div inside it and it has height given auto,I want to break the page if it is exceeding, can I apply page break to  tag?

Here is my demo HTML

```
<tr>
 <td><i><u>Assets:</u></i>   demo contentdemo contentdemo contentdemo contentdemo content demo content demo content demo contentdemo content demo contentdemo contentdemo contentdemo contentdemo content demo contentdemo contentdemo contentdemo content demo content demo content demo content </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td><div class="div_multiplelines" style="width: 100%; height: auto;"><?php echo $member_questionnaire_form_data->name_77 ?>&nbsp;</div></td>
</tr>
```

Also I want to make this dynamic,so Do I need to make it for every tr?
Maybe this cant be solution, how can I achieve that.
 I have given this css to my table

```
table{width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;  border-spacing: 0; /*table-layout: fixed;*/ page-break-inside: avoid;}
```

Comment: tr is block level element so, write like this `@media print {
            tr.page-break  { display: block; page-break-before: always; }
        } ` html `<tr class=" page-break">`

Comment: @MerajKhan will it apply automatically to tr if height is exceeding page height?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the question. Are you saying you want to move to the next page if the row is larger than a certain size? Also, I'll go ahead and note that Dompdf will not split a table row between pages at all with any release up through at least 0.8.x.

Comment: @BitsPlease Did you manage to resolve the issue? If so, could you please post the answer?